# Find the Cartesian representation of each curve represented by two parametric equations.

Tags: calculus, parametric

> Given the two equations $x(t) = acos(4t)$ and $y(t) = bsin(4t)$, find
>   $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and the Cartesian representation of the curve

I have already easily solved the first bit for $\frac{dy}{dx}$, the second part is a bit trickier. My first approach was to square both equations and write it in the $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ form, but the constants are different so I thought that'd make $r^2$ a bit tricky to figure out.
Then I decided I'd substitute one into the other, so I did as shown:

$$x(t) = acos(4t) \implies cos^{-1}(\frac{x}{a}) = 4t$$
$$\because y(t) = bsin(4t) \implies y(t) = bsin(cos^{-1}(\frac{x}{a}))$$
I wanted to simplify it further, I thought I'd approach this the same way a sine cancels out an inverse sine if it's in its argument and the result simplifies to the inverse sine's argument
$$sin(sin^{-1}(x)) = x$$
but I didn't know how I'd do that with an inverse cosine being the argument of a sine.
Can this be simplified further? Is there an easier (more direct) way to find the Cartesian representation than just trying to guess?

Comment: Did you try :$\frac{x(t)}{a}=\cos 4t$ and $\frac{y(t)}{b}=\sin 4t$, so squaring and summing, gives:$$\frac{x(t)^2}{a^2}+\frac{y(t)^2}{b^2}$$, replacing$$\cos^2 4t + \sin^2 4t=1$$, then $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$. This is the equation of an ellipse.